# Please don't follow us on [social-media]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[social-media](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/social-media) 266 questions

> Social media is the social interaction among people in which they create, share or exchange information and ideas in virtual communities and networks.

Seems to be a meta tag.

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

This is largely a roll-up meta tag for other specific social media (like [facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook)). Sometimes they lack the specific tag, sometimes not

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Not really. Writing social media platforms or using social media is off-topic

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

It lets you know there is something related to social media here. [Maybe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43478647/how-to-do-social-log-in-and-which-are-the-best-scripts-plug-in-for-it)

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No. The questions run the gamut from making social media to using specific instances of it with code.

Comment: Not only is it a meta tag but it doesn't mean anything at all. I don't think that adding it to a question in any way clarifies it. If somebody has a problem with, say, Twitter, then adding `social-media` gives you no new information. If they have a problem with something else that's not specific to Twitter or Facebook, etc., then the `social-media` tag is irrelevant. If it's asking for how to implement a social media or anything about social media as a general thing, it'd be too broad. Can't think of a way the tag improves a post.

Comment: That share link .. it's calling me strongly on this one ....

Answer (score 8):

Social media is broad and does nothing to help define the issues within a programming question. It's an umbrella to cover to many technologies/platforms.

Posts should be tagged with the relevant api tags (example the exact twitter tag [twitter-oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-oauth)) and not with a sweeping generalisation about what the question is about.